# MVC Moq multiple dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, moq, rhino-mocks

I am developing an application on ASP.NET MVC 4. I am using a TDD approach to develop my application. Initially, I am trying to implement a login module for the application. Technically in order to  login,it requires to follow these steps:

1. Verify user account is not locked and its a valid user. (If user attempt to login multiple times, it must lock the account after 5 unsuccessful attempt. To achieve this, I have a `LoginAttempt` field in my database, that I update after every unsuccessful attempt)
2. If account is verified, Validate the user with loginId and password using a third party service.
3. If verified, User must be redirected to Index page.

To achieve these task, I have created:

```
// Interface, Controller will interact with    
public Interface IAuthenticate
{
    bool ValidateUser(string UserId,string Password);
}

// Class that implement IAuthenticate
public class Authenticate : IAuthenticate
{ 

    private IVerifyUser loginVerify;
    private IThirdPartyService thirdpartyService;

    public Authenticate(IVerifyUser user,IThirdPartyService thirdparty)
    {    
        this.loginVerify=user;
        this.thirdpartyService=thirdparty;    
    }

    public bool ValidateUser(string userId,string password)
    {
        if(loginVerify.Verify(userId))
        {
            if(thirdpartyService.Validate(userId,password))
                return true;
            else 
                return false;    
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

To test my controller Login, DO I have to just create a mock for `IAuthenticate` or do I have to create mock for `IVerifyUser` and `IThirdPartyService` ??

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void Login_Rerturn_Error_If_UserId_Is_Incorrect()
 {
    Mock<IAuthenticate> mock1 = new Mock<IAuthenticate>();

    mock1.Setup(x => x.ValidateUser("UserIdTest", "PasswordTest"))
        .Returns(false);

    var results = controller.Login();
    var redirect = results as RedirectToRouteResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(results);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(results, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));

    controller.ViewData.ModelState.AssertErrorMessage("Provider", "User Id and Password is incorrect");

    Assert.AreEqual("Index", redirect.RouteValues["action"], "Wrong action");

    Assert.AreEqual("Home", redirect.RouteValues["controller"], "Wrong controller");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing your controller and your controller has a dependency on an instance of `IAuthenticate` then that is all your have to mock. By mocking it, you are disregarding any actual implementation within it. You are only testing the behaviour of the controller given the end behaviour occuring using `IAuthenticate`.

In your unit tests tests for your implementation of `IAuthenticate` you would then mock its dependencies (`IVerifyUser` and `IThirdPartyService`) to test how it behaves given a certain end result from either of their methods.

If you need any clarification, please comment! :)

Comment: Could you please provide more details? How would I do it, any guidelines will be really appreciated.

Comment: Also what if I have to test the IVerifyUser and IThirdPartyService??